# AnimationDrawable: how to catch animation end event

Tags: android, android-animation, animationdrawable

I have an `AnimationDrawable` that starts and I need to start a tween animation right after the first animation is ended.
I've seen `AnimationDrawable` doesn't have an `AnimationListener` setter, so how can I know when it is finished?

I've seen some solutions that compute the animation length and use an Handler, but they are not so accurate. In fact there is a (short) lag between the two animations.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you, you can call isRunning() method on related AnimationDrawable object and then check to see whether it is finished or not.

Comment: That's the solutions I talk about. The problem is it has a short lag between the two animations, probably due to delay of the function.